# How to configure SSL in sgcWebSockets 3.2?

Tags: delphi, ssl, ssl-certificate, sgc-websockets

I bought an SSL certificate and all I've got is a .crt file.

I need to configure a https server on Delphi correctly. I use a module named sgcWebSockets 3.2. As I can see in manual, I need to set the following parameters:

1) **SSLOptions/ CertFile/ KeyFile/ RootCertFile:** you 
need a certificate in .PEM format in order to encrypt 
websocket communications.

2) **SSLOptions/ Password:** this is optional and only 
needed if certificate has a password.

3) **SSLOptions/ Port:** port used on SSL connections.

But I have only a .crt file. I think I can convert it to .pem format using openssl. But what is this file will be? Is this a **CertFile** or **RootCertFile**? I haven't a **KeyFile** anyway. Will it works only with one cert file? I also haven't got any password. Should I leave this field empty? Please help.

Comment: IMHO it is easyer to use a reverse proxy server which also provides TLS - no SSL/TLS configuration is needed in Delphi anymore, and you have many other benefits

Comment: I would contact the certificate vendor customer support

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your crt file to a pem file with OpenSSL as follows:

```
 openssl x509 -inform der -in certificate.crt -out certificate.pem.
```

But that isn't the only file you need.  You also need your private key which was used to generate your csr that you sent to the certificate authority and that also has to be in pem format.  I'm not sure how you generated your csr, so I'd need more information to help you extract that or convert it to pem format.